# How to get date from different year, month and day columns in spark (scala)

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, date, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame including data like:

```
+----+-----+---+-----+
|Year|Month|Day|...  |
+----+-----+---+-----+
|2012|    2| 20|     |
|2011|    7|  6|     |
|2015|    3| 15|     |
```

and I would like to add a column with date

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Merge the columns together and then use `unix_timestamp` and `to_date` to get a timestamp column. For an input dataframe `df`:

```
df.withColumn("merge", concat_ws("-", $"Year", $"Month", $"Day"))
  .withColumn("date", to_date(unix_timestamp($"merge", "yyyy-MM-dd").cast("timestamp")))
  .drop("merge")
```

Comment: thank you, it worked. I thought i would have to mess around with the 0-s before the numbers as well (such as 06 instead of 6). This solution is much simpler than the things i was trying

Answer (score 5):

Not so complex as Shaido, just

```
df.withColumn("date", F.to_date(F.concat_ws("-", "Year", "Month", "Day")) ).show()
```

Work on spark 2.4 .

Answer (score 4):

For Spark 3+, you can use [`make_date`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#make_date) function:

```
df.withColumn("date", expr("make_date(Year, Month, Day)"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the `concat_ws` function to create a date in string data type and just cast that to date.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
//Source Data
val df = Seq((2012,2,20),(2011,7,6),(2015,3,15)).toDF("Year","Month","Day")
//using concat_ws function to create Date column and cast that column data type to date
val df1 = df.withColumn("Date",concat_ws("-",$"Year",$"Month",$"Day"))
.withColumn("Date",$"Date".cast("Date"))
display(df1)
```

You can see the output as below :

[image]